# Mutator elisp functions

Tags: elisp

How can I define mutator elisp functions? that is, how can I send parameters to an elisp function that can be modified inside the function for use outside the function (similar to non const reference variables or pointers in C++)? For example, suppose I had a function foo defined like

```
(defun foo (a b c d)
  ;do some stuff to b, c, and d
        .
        .
        .
  )
```

I might like to call it, say, as follows

```
(defun bar (x)
  (let ((a) (b) (c) (y))
  .
  .
  .
        ;a, b and c are nil at this point
        (foo x a b c)
        (setq y (some-other-function-of a b c x and-other-variables))
  .
  .
  .
)) ... ) 
  y)
```

I know that I could throw all my parameters local to some function into one big old list, evaluate the list at the end of the function and then go fetch these variables from some other list set to be the return value of that function (a list of stuff), i.e.

```
(setq return-list (foo read-only-x read-only-y))
(setq v_1 (car return-list))
(setq v_2 (cadr return-list))
            .
            .
```

but are there any better ways? All I have accomplished so far in my attempts to solve this is exiting the function with variables no different to how they were passed in

As for why I want to be able to do this I am simply trying refactor some large function F in such way that all collections of expressions related to some nameable concepts c live in their own little modules c_1, c_2, c_3, ... c_n that I can call from within F with whatever arguments I need to be updated along the way. That is to say, I would like F to look something like:

```
(defun F ( ... )
  (let ((a_1) (a_2) ... )
    (c_1 a_1 ... a_m)
    (c_2 a_h ... a_i)
     .
     .
     .
    (c_n a_j ... a_k)
     .
     .
     .
 ))...))
```

Comment: So you're starting with a file written in a poor style (e.g. where most vars start in a `let` that does not give them a value) and then want to make it even worse by moving the side effects elsewhere so they're even harder to track down?  You'll be better off returning the new values in a list (as you suggest).  You can decompose `return-list` more conveniently with `pcase-let`, as in `(pcase-let ((`(,v_1 ,v_2) (foo read-only-x read-only-y))) ..)`.

Comment: I take your point about the unassigned let variables taking no value (though in real code, given the opportunity, I will define them on declaration), as for side effects though, I'm not so sure I agree. With consistent variable naming conventions (i.e. i-var for read-only, o-var for write only, io-var for read and write, and so on...) then by just inspection I know which variables I intended would be subject to side-effects. And moreover, whether I assign values from a function return or via side-effects I still have to investigate the function fully to know what I got back in either case.

Comment: At any rate I am grateful for your response (and I am trying to improve my skills in this language - not least because it is immediately profitable to do so) and I didn't know about pcase-let

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of:

- make the "function" foo a macro and not a function (if possible)
- pass a newly created cons (or more of them) into the function, and replace the car and cdr of them via setcar/setcdr

In case the function is too complex, you can also combine both approaches - have a macro foo that creates a cons of a and b and calls a function foo0 with that cons, and later unpacks the car and cdr again.

In case you need more than 2 args, just use more than one cons as a paramter.

Comment: Thanks for that, I like the idea of the cons cell (I need to do some further reading on how to use macros properly)

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you how it can be done, but *please* don't do it, it's bad style.

```
(defun set-to (in-x out-y)
  (set out-y in-x))

(let (x)
  (set-to 10 'x)
  x)
```

There's a case when this won't work though:

```
(let (in-x)
  (set-to 10 'in-x)
  in-x)
```

It's a bit like this C++ code

```
void set_to(int x, int* y) {
    *y = x;
}

int y;
set_to(10, &y);
```

Actually I wish there were no non-const references in C++, so that
each mutator would have to be called with a pointer like above.

Again, *don't* do it unless it's *really* necessary.
Use instead `multiple-value-bind` or `cl-flet`.